# How to generate a RethinkDB changefeed for all tables in a database

Tags: python, rethinkdb, reql

I'm testing an API which inserts or deletes data in multiple tables of a RethinkDB database. In order to monitor what is happening to the database while using the API, I would like to print the changes in *all* its tables.

Here is some 'pseudo-code' of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import rethinkdb as r

# Prior to running this script, run "rethinkdb --port-offset 1" at the command line
conn = r.connect('localhost', 28016)
if 'test' in r.db_list().run(conn):
    r.db_drop('test').run(conn)
r.db_create('test').run(conn)

r.table_create('table1').run(conn)
r.table_create('table2').run(conn)

feed = r.table('table1' and 'table2').changes().run(conn)
for document in feed:
    print document
```

Prior to running this script, I would run `rethinkdb --port-offset 1` to initialize the RethinkDB database.

Once this script is running, I'd like to insert data into either `table1` or `table2` (using, for example, the web UI at `localhost:8081`) and see the changes printed in the terminal running the script. This appears not to work, however,
 because `r.table('table1' and 'table2')` is probably not a valid ReQL query.

How can I monitor changes in both tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can follow multiple changefeeds in a single query using `r.union`:

```
r.union(
  r.table('table1').changes(),
  r.table('table2').changes()
).run(conn)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up running the changefeeds for each table in a separate thread:

```
import rethinkdb as r
import threading

# Prior to running this script, run "rethinkdb --port-offset 1" at the command line
conn = r.connect('localhost', 28016)

def clear_test_database():
    '''Clear the contents of the "test" database by dropping and re-creating it.'''
    if 'test' in r.db_list().run(conn):
        r.db_drop('test').run(conn)
    r.db_create('test').run(conn)

clear_test_database()

def monitor_changes(table_name, conn):
    feed = r.table(table_name).changes().run(conn)
    for document in feed:
        print document

tables = ['table1', 'table2']

for table in tables:
    conn = r.connect('localhost', 28016)
    r.table_create(table).run(conn)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=monitor_changes, args=(table, conn))
    thread.start()
```

Note that I re-define the `conn` connection object within the for-loop as these objects are not thread-safe.

To test the method, I opened the web UI at `localhost:8081` and used the following `insert` command:

[image]

In the Sublime runner I see the changes being added every time I press the "Run" button:

[image]

This works both when I choose `table1` or `table2` in the `insert` command.